# OpenERP, dynamic DOMAIN in view

Tags: view, odoo

I work with OpenERP and I try to create a new form view for the account_bank_statement_line object. so when i create a new statement line the statement object must in open state so far no problem i solved with domain in the field tag attribute, But when I try to view the satatement after confirming the cash;  the statement_id  will desapear becouse it state is confirmed how can I solve this probleme can sommeone help me

```
<field colspan="2"  name="statement_id" domain="[('state','=','open')]" attrs="{'readonly':[('state','=', 'confirm')]}" widget="selection"  string="Cash Register"/>
<field colspan="6" name="amount" attrs="{'readonly':[('state','=', 'confirm')]}"  />
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

try adding the domain, `domain="[('state','in',['open','confirm'])]"`

Comment: Thank Omal for your responding, but i d'ont want to list all confirmed cash (statement_id) at the creation moment  of new  statement_line. I want to list only opened and get filled form after the confirming the cash.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I don't really see what is hiding your field "statement_id". The fields are visible by default and can be hidden by the *invisible* attribute. Try to add it explicitly to your field definition:

```
<field colspan="2"  name="statement_id" 
    invisible="0"
    domain="[('state','=','open')]" 
    attrs="{'readonly':[('state','=', 'confirm')]}" 
    widget="selection"  string="Cash Register"/>
```